# sort in bash, sort based part of column

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file like:

```
a1 blah
b2 blah
a3 blah
b1 blah
b3 blah
a2 blah
```

if I do

```
sort -k1,1 file.name
```

I'll get this:

```
a1
a2
a3
b1
b2
b3
```

However, I want to get this order:

```
a1
b1
a2
b2
a3
b3
```

how can I do that? Thanks

Edit: I edited the example, the previous one didn't present the whole problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `sort -kN.M`! `N.M` indicates `sort` to start from the Mth character on Nth field.

Initial solution:

```
sort -k1.2 your_file
```

Updated one:

```
sort -k1.2,k1.2 your_file
```

so it will *just* sort by this specific character and won't go further.

Output:

```
a1 blah
b1 blah
a2 blah
b2 blah
a3 blah
b3 blah
```

Comment: My solution still fits on your desired output. Can you elaborate a little more what is wrong?

Comment: @user2207811 try `sort -k1.2,1.2 your_file`

Comment: OK, now I see the difference. As `blah` would be something different, `a1 blah` would be after `b1 alah` with my answer. Thanks @ravoori. Anyway, user2207811, if your input is not representative and the question does not explicitly state the problem then don't be surprised when an answer doesn't not work for cases that you failed to mention.

Comment: OK, thanks. We all learnt something: me the `sort -k1.2,1.2` issue. You to indicate proper input and output. Cheers!